# Postfix 530 5.7.0 authentication required

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, postfix, dovecot

не могу с почтового ящика отправить письмо на определённое доменное имя, как и они мне.
Лог:

```
Feb 13 17:07:31 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[10852]: connect from mx.domain.ru[94.124.196.138]
Feb 13 17:07:31 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[10852]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mx.domain.ru[94.124.196.138]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Feb 13 17:07:31 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[10852]: BBB3F8488274: client=mx.sotrans.ru[94.124.196.138], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=development@mydomain.ru
Feb 13 17:07:31 localhost postfix/cleanup[10859]: BBB3F8488274: message-id=<!&!AAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAAAAAAK/3vuxpKtRPtESHRpEHvNbCgAAAEAAAAH5BeQTTh0tOigPiFT5FjUQBAAAAAA==@mydomain.ru>
Feb 13 17:07:32 localhost postfix/qmgr[10838]: BBB3F8488274: from=<development@trucks.ru>, size=4625, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 13 17:07:32 localhost postfix/smtp[10861]: Untrusted TLS connection established to mx.domain.ru[94.124.196.138]:25: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Feb 13 17:07:32 localhost postfix/smtp[10861]: BBB3F8488274: to=<webmaster@domain.ru>, relay=mx.domain.ru[94.124.196.138]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0.4/0.01/0.56/0.07, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host mx.sotrans.ru[94.124.196.138] said: 530 5.7.0 Authentication required (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Feb 13 17:07:32 localhost postfix/cleanup[10859]: DE2B68488276: message-id=<20200213140732.DE2B68488276@s056574cf.mydomain.ru>
Feb 13 17:07:32 localhost postfix/bounce[10862]: BBB3F8488274: sender non-delivery notification: DE2B68488276
Feb 13 17:07:32 localhost postfix/qmgr[10838]: DE2B68488276: from=<>, size=6675, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 13 17:07:32 localhost postfix/qmgr[10838]: BBB3F8488274: removed
Feb 13 17:07:33 localhost postfix/pipe[10864]: DE2B68488276: to=<development@domain.ru>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.16, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Feb 13 17:07:33 localhost postfix/qmgr[10838]: DE2B68488276: removed
Feb 13 17:07:34 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[10852]: disconnect from mx.sotrans.ru[94.124.196.138] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
```

main.cf

```
### Config
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mydomain = mydomain.ru
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
#in_flow_delay = 1s
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps, $virtual_alias_maps

home_mailbox = Maildir/
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

mail_owner = postfix
setgid_group = postdrop

html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES

virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit=1

### Auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =


#relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/mysql_relay_domains.cf

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains =
   mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
   mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps =
   mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf

virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_client_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
        permit

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        permit

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unlisted_recipient,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        permit

smtpd_data_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_multi_recipient_bounce,
    permit

smtpd_etrn_restrictions = reject
smtpd_helo_required = yes

smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = etrn, silent-discard
smtpd_forbidden_commands = CONNECT GET POST
disable_vrfy_command = yes

### TLS
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/certs/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file =  /etc/postfix/certs/key.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
```

Comment: В первом приближении, я вижу как минимум одну вещь относящуюся к проблеме и вторую, которая может сыграть злую шутку, если сервер не стоит где-нибудь на хостинге. main.cf:
`smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes` попробуйте поменять на `no`
`mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8` Добавить сюда подсети локальной сети, если сервер не стоит где-нибудь на хостинге.

Comment: Сервер стоит на хостинге. Сейчас попробую, поменять.

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Тут пишут что проблема может быть из-за неверно прописанного хоста. https://serverfault.com/questions/857592/postfix-relay-via-ses-530-authentication-required